# PowerBi: how can I show corresponding string on y axis labels

Tags: plot, powerbi, label

In powerbi on line chart I would like to see corresponding labels from another column; values on y axis should be from 1-3 in this order but instead of numbers we should see names from second column.

Nb. - y Axis value

Nb.word - y Axis label

Value - x Axis label and value

Sample data:

| Nb. | Nb.word | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Started. | 40. |
| 2 | On Hold. | 30. |
| 1 | Started. | 50. |
| 3 | Done. | 35. |

Comment: Not able to understand the data correctly. Can you maybe share it in Tabular format (Check https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post)? And what exactly are you trying to achieve? You want Nb to be on Y-Axis, Nb.Word on Y-Axis Label? and Value to be on X-Axis Value, if I am correct?

Comment: I want on y axis data ordered from 1-3 but instead of numers show text value

Comment: Add your sample expected output from the above data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a sort column for `Nb.word`, so that `Nb.` is used as sorting. To do this, you must:

1. Select the column that you want to sort in the right hand side fields panel, in this case, `Nb.word`. In the ribbon, the `Column tools` tab becomes active.
2. Select Sort by Column, then select the field you want to sort the other field by, in this case, `Nb.`. Note that for this to work, there can only be 1 unique value in `Nb.` column for the corresponding value in `Nb.word`. In your sample data, this is true, since for every row where `Nb.word` is `Started.`, the corresponding value in `Nb.` is `1`.

After completing these steps you might not see immediate results in your visuals. Try to remove and add back fields in your visuals to see the effect if not immediately apparent. When you use `Nb.word` now, for example as category labels, the values will be sorted according to the `Nb.` column sorting - just as you wanted.